# How can I back up Google Datastore for efficient restoration?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

Google Datastore has a [backup utility](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/datastore-backing-up-restoring). But it is far too slow for a operational  database, taking hours to  run a backup or restoration of a few dozen GB. Also, Google recommends disabling Cloud Datastore writes during backup, which again is impossible for an operational database.

How can I backup my Datastore so that if there is data corruption, I can rapidly restore, losing at most a few minutes of transactions?

It seems that this is an essential part of any full-strength database system.

(Other databases provide this with

- append-only storage or
- periodic backups augmented with a differential backup or transaction log or
- realtime mirroring, though that doesn't handle the case of data corruption from a bug that writes to the database.)

Comment: Yeap, big issue

Comment: Note, a better version is under-development. Also worth noting you don't need to implement realtime mirroring since the database is run in a multi-master multi-region replication setup, so 'mirroring' is handled for you. If a few of our data centers go down - you'll still be up and running.

Comment: @DanMcGrath Thank you. Will that new backup require disabling writes, like today's backup? (That's not possible on a production database). When will be be released?

Comment: @JoshuaFox you can back it up without disabling writes and the consistency will be at the entity-group level. If you require consistency across the entire dataset, you need to disable writes - this is in line with all large scale distributed databases today. I can't give out dates.

Comment: @DanMcGrath
"a better version is under-development."

What specifically is better about it?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't going to get a "few minutes" latency with an "eventually consistent" nosql datastore like this in order to protect yourself from yourself with a *naive back up* of everything. You really should invest in good testing to make sure that no bugs like this exist in the first place.

Your only real solution is to use immutable data and versioning, since this is how all the *other* nosql systems do it as well. The datastore key system that exists already can works well for this and is extremely fast.

Never update anything and you never corrupt anything or lose anything and can roll back to individual records to previous revisions very quickly.

Archive the older revisions at some point to the cloud bucket store at some point to save money on storage or delete after a fixed number of revisions.

Comment: Thank you. "Testing... that no bugs like this exist." Yes, but I am not going to bet my business on that. Backups are still needed. Besides bugs, there can be data corruption on the infrastructure, as well as hacks.

Comment: "Your only real solution is to use immutable data and versioning, since this is how all the other nosql systems do it as well." Yes, I may have to implement that. Why doesn't Google do that for me? Their implementation of an eventually consistent data store is all about making sure that "replicas" of data sync up. That is not the same as backup, but it looks like they are well-over half-way there.

Comment: "You aren't going to get a "few minutes" latency." Yes, I realize that my requirements are probably unfeasible. But what is the best that can be done? Google Datastore's own backup utility seems basically useless for an operational datastore given that you have to pause writes for many hours.

Comment: what you want is not *backups* what you want is *versioning* like I describe and that is the only solution for this problem domain.

Answer (score 2):

The backup utility starts MapReduce jobs in the background to parallelize the backup/restore and perform it faster. However, it seems to shard the entities by namespace. If your data is on one or few namespaces the process can be very slow.

You could implement your own parallel backup/restore mecanism by using a tool like AppEngine MapReduce[1](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce) or Cloud Dataflow[2](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) to make it faster.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about that issue with namespacing. This still  doesn't solve the problem of backups, but it makes an important point that the bundled utility is not efficent.

Comment: Implementing my own may be the way to go. Why MapReduce or Dataflow rather than Spark? Or Task Queues for that matter?

Comment: Your options are also valid, I just thought of two of the tools GCP offers to run embarassingly parallel tasks like this one. You also may want to double check if this is still the current behavior, since I have just deployed the Datastore Admin to double check and now it is being able to shard on a single namespace both on backup and restore jobs. This may have been added recently. When you create a job there will be a link to see details on the sharding.